# Get text outside one tag and inside another

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I am parsing a web page with BeautifulSoup, and it has some elements like the following:

```
<td><font size="2" color="#00009c"><b>Consultant Registration Number  :</b></font>  16043646</td>
```

The structure always seems to be a `<td>` with the first part surrounded by `<font><b>`, and the text after the `</font>` tag can be empty. How can I get that text that is after the font tag?

In this example I would want to get `"16043646"`. If the html was instead

```
<td><font size="2" color="#00009c"><b>Consultant Registration Number  :</b></font></td>
```

I would want to get `""`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> text1 = '<td><font size="2" color="#00009c"><b>Consultant Registration Number  :</b></font>  16043646</td>'
>>> text2 = '<td><font size="2" color="#00009c"><b>Consultant Registration Number  :</b></font></td>'
>>> BeautifulSoup(text1).td.font.nextSibling
u'  16043646'
>>> BeautifulSoup(text2).td.font.nextSibling
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at that that part of the docs but I did not realize that nextSibling got text outside of tags.